# Change default gateway to specific address on second interface

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing

I currently have two servers, and **both** servers have (and are using) two ports.  In short, I need to change the default gateway of one of the servers from it's default `eth0` address / gateway to an internal `eth1` address, effectively using the other server as a router/gateway.

The process I've used is not working - when I change the default route on the second server to the first, internet / `eth0` access stops (but local network  / `eth1` access continues).  What am I doing wrong?

Side note: due to very annoying business politics, the servers *cannot* be moved onto another switch, or anything of the like (which I would much prefer, but alas, I don't have the authority).

So the first server, which I will call Server A, has the following (where X.X.X.X is the public ip address and G.G.G.G is the gateway):

```
:~# ip route show
default via G.G.G.G dev eth0 onlink
10.11.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.11.0.8
10.130.0.0/16 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.130.12.252
X.X.X.X/XX dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src X.X.X.X
```

Furthermore, Server A has been set to allow IP forwarding:

```
:~# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1


:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             LOG level warning

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination


:~# cat /etc/iptables/rules.v4
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LOG
COMMIT
```

Now, on the second server - **server B** - after performing `ip route replace default via 10.130.12.252 dev eth1 onlink` it has the following (where Y.Y.Y.Y is this server's public IP address):

```
:~# ip route show
default via 10.130.12.252 dev eth1 onlink
10.46.0.0/16 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.46.0.7
10.130.0.0/16 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.130.112.24
Y.Y.Y.Y/YY dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src Y.Y.Y.Y
```

Again, this causes **server B** to lose all internet access (not just dns - `ping 8.8.8.8` hangs on server B, but continues to work on Server A), yet it still can access the `10.130.0.0/16` network).  Changing the default route back to G.G.G.G restores internet access.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get this working?

Comment: Your setup seems OK. I think you need to provide more details about the network setup and IP addressing used on both servers and how they are connected to the their gateway.

Comment: Can you see anything in the firewall logs of server A?

Comment: Start `ping 8.8.8.8` and watch packets on `eth0` and `eth1` on the server A, pay attention to source IP address. Also check `iptables` on the server B, maybe there are some NAT rules.